# How to optimize canvas image and get jpg instead of png

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<img id='imgt' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>

var img = document.getElementById("imgt");
    c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");

    var a = $('#imgt').width();
    var b = $('#imgt').height();

    c1.width = a;
    c1.height = b;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, a, b);
```

So resulting image is the same dimensions as source img, but it has over 1MB while the source image is less than 1MB.

Also the source image is `jpg` and resulting image is `png`.

How can I get `jpg` instead of `png` and how to optimize resulting image for web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you' re making the data URI you can specify

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.95);
```

or

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){...}, 'image/jpeg', 0.95);
```

which will generate a JPG. Just make sure your picture is opaque, because otherwise the background will become black.

Comment: @bonaca How are you currently generating your PNG if not using a DataURL? If you're using `toBlob` the mime type is the second argument instead of the first.